# php for doing this replacement

Tags: php, regex

i have this data in my database row and i want to replace 4205476 integer with 42/05/47/6 this integer. i can extract the numbers using preg match all but again i am confused how to achieve this 
this is one row of mysql and if all numbers after image are replaced it will look like this(see next line)

> `Mario Ermito photos by sample.com Mario Ermito Latest News, Photos, Biography, Videos and Wallpapers [img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/4205476/600full-mario-ermito.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/4453948/600full-my-profile.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/427185/600full-eagle-eye-poster.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/1323868/600full-alexis-bledel.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/2505314/600full-monroe-lee.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/3300481/600full-cindy-crawford.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/1046646/600full-pitura-freska.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/4322305/600full-kristin-kreuk.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/4261476/600full-kang-so--ra.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/3386911/600full-summer-brielle.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/4663949/600full-the-closer-artwork.jpg[/img]`

after replacement it will look like this

> `Mario Ermito photos by sample.com Mario Ermito Latest News, Photos, Biography, Videos and Wallpapers [img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/42/05/47/6/600full-mario-ermito.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/44/53/94/8/600full-my-profile.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/42/71/85/600full-eagle-eye-poster.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/13/23/86/8/600full-alexis-bledel.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/25/05/31/4/600full-monroe-lee.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/33/00/48/1/600full-cindy-crawford.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/10/46/64/6/600full-pitura-freska.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/43/22/30/5/600full-kristin-kreuk.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/42/61/47/6/600full-kang-so--ra.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/33/86/91/1/600full-summer-brielle.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/46/63/94/9/600full-the-closer-artwork.jpg[/img]`

i  tried to extract the number from this input and i could do this with this pattern but what next ?? very confused .first thought of adding with string but not able to decide how to achieve

```
 ~\/\image\/(.*?)\/~
```

Comment: This looks like a literal replacement, so [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) would work...

Comment: can you please tell me how you extract the number from the string ?

Comment: "one row of mysql"? Mysql regexes perform matching only. they can NOT do replacement.

Comment: @GauravParashar  preg match all  ~\/\image\/(.*?)\/~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `wordwrap` coupled with `array_walk`

```
<?php
$str='     Mario Ermito photos by sample.com Mario Ermito Latest News, Photos, Biography, Videos and Wallpapers [img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/4205476/600full-mario-ermito.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/4453948/600full-my-profile.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/427185/600full-eagle-eye-poster.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/1323868/600full-alexis-bledel.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/2505314/600full-monroe-lee.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/3300481/600full-cindy-crawford.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/1046646/600full-pitura-freska.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/4322305/600full-kristin-kreuk.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/4261476/600full-kang-so--ra.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/3386911/600full-summer-brielle.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/4663949/600full-the-closer-artwork.jpg[/img]';
preg_match_all('~\/\image\/(.*?)\/~', $str, $matches); echo "<pre>";
$matchesarray = $matches[1];
array_walk($matches[1],function (&$v){ $v = wordwrap($v, 2, "/", true);});
$replacearray = $matches[1];

$str = str_replace($matchesarray,$replacearray,$str);
echo $str;
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

> Mario Ermito photos by sample.com Mario Ermito Latest News, Photos, Biography, Videos and Wallpapers
>   [img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/42/05/47/6/600full-mario-ermito.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/44/53/94/8/600full-my-profile.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/42/71/85/600full-eagle-eye-poster.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/13/23/86/8/600full-alexis-bledel.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/25/05/31/4/600full-monroe-lee.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/33/00/48/1/600full-cindy-crawford.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/10/46/64/6/600full-pitura-freska.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/43/22/30/5/600full-kristin-kreuk.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/42/61/47/6/600full-kang-so--ra.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/33/86/91/1/600full-summer-brielle.jpg[/img][img]http://xyz.sample.com/image/46/63/94/9/600full-the-closer-artwork.jpg[/img]

#### How it was done ?

First use `preg_match_all` and grab all those numbers and keep it in a separate array , now use `array_walk` to split the strings with slashes , finally do a simple `str_replace` on the original string.

Comment: you are master. i am also from chennai . will be obliged to have a frnd like u.bydbest at  gmail

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [regular expression](http://regex101.com/r/gF4lP7):

```
(?<=image/)(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d)(?=/)
```

That will capture the sets of 2, 2, 2, and 1 digits in between `image/` and `/`.  You can then use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace) to replace your string with `/` in between each set of digits.

```
$string = 'http://xyz.sample.com/image/4205476/600full-mario-ermito.jpg';
$regex = '~(?<=image/)(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d)(?=/)~';

$string = preg_replace($regex, '$1/$2/$3/$4', $string);
echo $string; // http://xyz.sample.com/image/42/05/47/6/600full-mario-ermito.jpg
```

Working example: [ideone](http://ideone.com/oEIRPR)

---

**Explanation:**

The regular expression starts with `(<?=image/)` which "looks behind" for the string `image/`. Then we use capturing groups (in parentheses, so we can access with `$1`, `$2`, etc) of `\d` (which is a "shorthand" character class for `[0-9]`).  We specify the number of digits in each match group on the curly brackets, so we are capturing 2 digits, 2 digits, 2 digits, then one digit.  Finally the regular expression ends with `(?=/)` with "looks ahead" for the string `/`.  We now officially have matched a string `image/1234567/` with captured groups of `12`, `34`, `56`, `7`.

We use PHP's regular expression function, `preg_replace()`, to match your string and replace it with our capture groups (adding `/` in between each one).

```
preg_replace('~(?<=image/)(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d)(?=/)~', '$1/$2/$3/$4', $string);
```

Comment: awesome but request you please explain how you did this

Comment: @sachin I added a more in depth of how the regular expression works and how we use it in PHP.

Comment: it fails for 6 digits please see third line of your output http://xyz.sample.com/image/427185/600ful